# How to : Press effect on text only icon in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have a text only icon in action bar with label name = Cancel. Would like to have my own press effect, on click of cancel button. My objective is to change text color on press of cancel button

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/cancel"
          android:title="cancel />
</menu>
```

This is how my action bar looks like with the cancel button.

Looks like there is no way to use a selector here.

[image: Action bar with cancel button]

Comment: text color, means color of cancel text?

Comment: You wanna staying actionBar icon?

Comment: @RobiKumarTomar Yes.  NoXSaeeD -  Its not an icon its an item with text. no icon.